Форматирование даты в роботе битрикс24
Я делаю робота в битрикс24 и мне важно туда вставить дату, которую я вычисляю, но без времени.
Если я пишу {{=dateadd({{Дата начала}}, "+19d")}} внутри текста, то получаю дату со временем, хотя {{Дата начала}} изначально без времени получается. В итоге я хотел привести к удобному мне формату таким образом: {{ =date("d.m.Y", {{Планируемая дата доставки}}) }} и пробовал {{ =date("d.m.Y", {{=dateadd({{Дата начала}}, "+19d")}}) }}, однако ничего не получилось.


В общем получилось сначала сделать робота с изменением параметра с той датой +19 дней. И ее потом использовать с функцией date:
{{=date("d.m.Y", {{Планируемая дата доставки}})}}

У меня получилось вот так:
{{=date('d.m.y', dateadd({=Variable:data_edu > printable}, '7 days'))}}


Я дошел в итоге до такого варианта. Мне нужно было добавлять к текущей дате переменную с количеством дней.
Результат:
=dateadd({=System:Now}, {{Число}} & "d")

Ну и, если результат нужно вставить в строковое поле вместе с другими данными, например:
Текст {{=date("d.m.Y", dateadd({=System:Now}, {{Число}} & "d"))}}

